How can I access the Blur, Smear and Gradient tool for weight painting in Blender 4.2.1?
I can't find any help in the manual on where the tools are. There are apparently in the Blend options but they aren't there either.


In the 3D window, when in Weight Paint Mode, press T to open the toolshelf on the left.

